# return single rows from one table that don't match other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

so i have two tables. I'm trying to join two tables and only return records from table a that don't have a match in table b.  i'm stumped so far.

## Table A

```
--------------------
name amount     date
--------------------
bob     250 4/8/2010
dan     100 4/8/2010
sla     222 4/8/2010
obo     344 4/8/2010
bob     100 4/8/2010
```

## Table B

```
--------------------
name amount     date
--------------------
bob     250 4/8/2010
dan     100 4/8/2010
sla     500 4/8/2010
obo     300 4/8/2010
bob     100 4/8/2010
```

Comment: Depending on your sql version, `MINUS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the canonical ways to do this in SQL is using an [outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins/448080#448080):

```
select a.*
from a left outer join b
on (
  a."name" = b."name"
  and a."amount" = b."amount"
  and a."date" = b."date"
) where b."name" is null
and b."amount" is null
and b."date" is null
```

The left outer join  returns all rows from the table on the left of the join, whether or not they match rows from the table on the right side of the join. But when rows from the left table don't have a match in the right table, the columns of the right table are set to `null`. You can thus filter out all rows that *did* match and return only rows from the left table that *didn't* match.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for. this is way faster than the way i was doing it before with multiple selects.

Comment: @morgan - you mean a correlated subquery like Notulysses' answer? Yeah, correlated subqueries are usually a lot slower than joins.

Comment: yah. That's basically what i was doing but with more complexity. it was mind-blowingly slow. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM b 
                  WHERE name = a.name 
                    AND amount = a.amount 
                    AND date = a.date)
```